# while loop inside gitlab yaml pipeline

Tags: bash, gitlab, yaml, sh, gitlab-ci

There is supposed to be a multi-line command (while ... do script) in the script section of my .yml file. It basically supposed to copy the files from the current commit to a specific location in the docker image.

For some reason, the pipeline is throwing an error. See below.

Below is the content of my .gitlab-ci.yml file

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - transform
    
Transform:
  stage: transform
  image:
    name: some-ubuntu-image
    entrypoint: [""]
  except:
    - master
  script:
    - mkdir /opt/input-files
    
    - |
      i=0
      while read line
      do
        array[ $i ]="$line"
        cp -p --parents "$line" /opt/input-files/
        ((i++))
      done < <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA);

    - echo "Displaying copied files"
    - ls -a /opt/input-files/
```

**Job Error:**

```
$ mkdir /opt/input-files
$ i=0
$ while read line; do # collapsed multi-line command
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine it's one line.

Add newlines then.

You could write:

```
 i=0; while read line; do array[i]="$line"; cp -p --parents "$line" /opt/input-files/;  ((i++)); done < <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA);
```

or with newlines:

```
 i=0;
 while read line; do
    array[i]="$line";
    cp -p --parents "$line" /opt/input-files/;
    ((i++));
done < <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA);
```

and just inside gitlab:

```
script:
- i=0;
  while read line; do
    array[i]="$line";
    cp -p --parents "$line" /opt/input-files/;
    ((i++));
  done < <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA);
```